# How to take text from a txt document and create a new directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, directory

The challenge is to take a name from a text file and create a new folder in a different directory. My issue is that when I attempt to do so it mentions that the

```
join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'list'
```

Is there a way of converting a list to do this or is there another way of doing this I'm not seeing?

```
import os

clientnames = "/home/michael/tafe/Customer Service Team/Customer Service Team new client names" #filepath/filename of new client names.

#Error handeling, if the txt file is missing then it will say the file is unavaliable.
if (os.path.isfile(clientnames)) == True:
    print("The file is avaliable, folder creation will now start.")
else:
    print("The file is unavaliable, please provide Customer Service Team new client names .txt file")

folderdir = "/home/michael/tafe/FS1/Administration/New_Customers" #filepath of where the new folders are to be created in.

#take name from txt file.
with open(clientnames, "r") as newfolder:
    for line in newfolder:
        newfolder = line.strip().split()
        created_folder = os.path.join(folderdir, newfolder)

os.mkdir(created_folder)
print("Directory '% s' created" % newfolder)
```

I am pretty new to learning python but feel like I'm close to figuring this out once I find how to get the directory created. (there are some other parts to the challenge as well but are not related to this...).

Using Python 3.8.7 64-bit on Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Well, `newfolder` is a list so it is not clear what it is you are trying to achieve but perhaps try `os.path.join(folderdir, *newfolder)`. Note the asterisk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.path.join` accepts only strings, and you are passing a list as a second argument. E.g. lets assume your `newfolder` looks like this: `['folder1', 'folder2', 'etc']`, your call to this function looks like:

```py
>>> os.path.join(folderdir, ['folder1', 'folder2', 'etc'])
# error
```

Instead you have to pass only strings, like:

```py
os.path.join(folderdir, 'folder1', 'folder2', 'etc')
# 'folderdir/folder1/folder2/etc'
```

To do this, you can use *splat* operator, to unpack argument lists:

```py
os.path.join(folderdir, *newfolder)
# 'folderdir/folder1/folder2/etc'
```

**Update** the other problem as pointed by @Ann Zen is the for loop. Each iteration changes `created_folder` variable, which is used only after loop. You need to read all text from file (as list), then after loop join it into path using `*newfolder`.

```py
with open(clientnames, "r") as newfolder:
    newfolder = newfolder.read()
    newfolder = [t for t in newfolder.split(' ') if len(t)>0]
created_folder = os.path.join(folderdir, *newfolder)
```

**Update 2**  Another problem is when you are trying to create multiple nested folders in a path, *e.g. create folder test1 in folder test2, but folder test2 doesn't exist yet, so need to be created first.*
Assuming each folder is named in another line in file `clientnames`:

```py
with open(clientnames, "r") as newfolder:
    folderpath = folderdir
    for line in newfolder.readlines():
        foldername = line.strip()
        folderpath = os.path.join(folderpath, foldername)
        os.mkdir(folderpath)
```

Then if the file `clientnames` looks like this:

```
test1
test2
test3
```

it will first create `folderdir/test1`, then `folderdir/test1/test2`, and at the end `folderdir/test1/test2/test3`, so not to throw `FileNotFoundError`

**Update 3**  If you want to create folder for each line of text from `clientnames`, all rooted in `folderdir` simply don't stack the path, and create new one for each line.

```py
with open(clientnames, "r") as newfolder:
    for line in newfolder.readlines():
        foldername = line.strip()
        folderpath = os.path.join(folderdir, foldername)
        os.mkdir(folderpath)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for having a look over the code, I've implemented both yours and @Ann Zens code and while I am able to create a new folder it is only accepting the first character of the text in the .txt file. Adding more that 1 character to the txt file shows an error:

Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundError
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/michael/tafe/FS1/Administration/New_Customers/A/c/m/e/_/C/o/r/p/e/r/a/t/i/o/n'

Does this have to do with the way the code is reading the txt file or is this just how the splat operator works?

Comment: @MadMike It shows the error because instead of path `/home/michael/tafe/FS1/Administration/New_Customers/Acme_Corporation` you try to create `/home/michael/tafe/FS1/Administration/New_Customers/A/c/m/e/_/C/o/r/p/e/r/a/t/i/o/n` and to do this all the previous folders have to exist, eg. folder `/home/michael/tafe/FS1/Administration/New_Customers/A/c/m/e/_/C/o/r/p/e/r/a/t/i/o` (which doesn't exists). So the problem falls to reading the file. `Split(' ')` should divide your text on every space. What does your file `clientnames` contain?

Comment: All the clientnames .txt file has is "Acme Corporation" no other text, white space or apostrophes (""). If you open up a txt doc and type Acme Corporation that's all that's in the file.

Comment: Adding the .split() to newfolder = line.strip().split() shows the following error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/michael/tafe/FS1/Administration/New_Customers/Acme/Corperation'
looks like split is now just separating the two txt by the space

Comment: For reading just one line, you can use `newfolder.read().strip()`. If you would try to create multiple nested folders, then checkout update 2 to my answer.

Comment: Dude, your awesome! This has helped tremendously! Out of curiosity, if I had wanted to add multiple folders to the same New_Customers folder how would I go about it?

i.e. For every line in the txt file a new folder is created in the New_Customers folder, not nested like you had mentioned.

Comment: Hey mate, thanks for your update 3. Can you please elaborate more on that, bit confused/unsure what you mean by not stacking the path, and create new one for each line.

Comment: I had tested with the code you showed in Update 3 and it appears to just take the last line of the txt doc and then create that folder, for example:
.
Acme-Corperation
Test
.
Test folder is added under the directory.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the `for` loop of:

```
with open(clientnames, "r") as newfolder:
    for line in newfolder:
        newfolder = line.strip().split()
        created_folder = os.path.join(folderdir, newfolder)
```

`star.split()` returns an object of type `list`. Knowing that `newFolder` will be a `list`,

```
created_folder = os.path.join(folderdir, newfolder)
```

Is like

```
created_folder = os.path.join("/home/michael/tafe/FS1/Administration/New_Customers", ["Tom", "Lam"])
```

How would python join the string with the list?

Remove the `.split()` and see what happens.